# Click event while clicking on navigation link through ID

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I am working in the word-press theme. On one of my page there are around 10 tabs which opens separately.

what I have done so far is I in my navigation bar i gave links to all tabs

for example

`href="mylink.com/#tabid"`

It works fine when my page redirects from another page but while on the same page This don't work

my jQuery

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("spser") > -1) {
      jQuery("#spser").click();
    }
```

Update:

(I am new to the Jquery)

What happens ... my navigation bar is wp plugin so may b it dosen't consider links is on same page.

another thing i am trying to do is get link id and then change tab

here is idea

```
jQuery("#".window.location.href.lastIndex()).click();
```

something like this

Answer (score 0):

**you can use this**

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("spser") > -1) {
      jQuery("#spser").trigger('click');
    }
```

Comment: what you want to do when page redirects

Comment: Certain tab to open suppose i have 3 options healtcare,pricing,help on my navigation bar. when i click on the any of that link it have to open the tab of each option.When i click option of healthcare from home page...(now the page open which have healthcare tab)....healthcare tab opens... but again I try to open any other options suppose pricing from the navigation menu it dosent work

Comment: also see what error you are getting in console window

Comment: there is no error.... i checked..i cant share html bcoz i am working in the wordpress

Comment: why are you using id in href? and also see are you using same id for all tabs?

Comment: using id in href to redirect page on that certain tab if i am not on same page. every tab have diffrent ID